# сохранять ответы сервера после каждого запроса и выводить их в HTML тег

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Стандартная ситуация для AJAX: отправил форму -> сервер получил, проверил -> сервер ответил -> вывели в тег, например `<div id="answer"></div>`

Здесь все нормально.

Задача: после каждой отправки формы предыдущий ответ, который уже есть в `<div id="answer"></div>` сохранять и показывать в том же теге плюс новый ответ. Т.е. какбы "лог", но только для текущей сессии.

Выглядеть это, по моим представлениям должно так:

Первая отправка формы:

```
<div id="answer">
<p>Ответ от сервера 1</p>
</div>
```

Вторая отправка формы:

```
<div id="answer">
<p>Ответ от сервера 2</p>
<p>Ответ от сервера 1</p>
</div>
```

Третья отправка формы:

```
<div id="answer">
<p>Ответ от сервера 3</p>
<p>Ответ от сервера 2</p>
<p>Ответ от сервера 1</p>
</div>
```

**Вопрос:** Такое вообще возможно без использования баз данных? Если да, то куда копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не нужно хранить ответы вообще то можно так:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#but').click(function () {
        var otvetu = $('#answer').html(); //получаем ответы которые уже получили
        var resultat_zaprosa = '<p>Ответ от сервера n</p>'; // сдесь результат нового запроса
        
        otvetu = otvetu + resultat_zaprosa; //добавляем новый ответ к старым
        
        $('#answer').html(otvetu); //вставляем в блок ответы
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="answer">
<p>Ответ от сервера 1</p>
</div>

<button id="but">Knopka</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Без бд можно сохранять в localstorage, sessionstorage или куки с помощью js. Все данные будут храниться в браузере. И их можно будет дёргать после перезагрузки страницы.